# How to solve the duplicate integer issue in an array for the isValidSubsequence(array, sequence) question

Tags: python, arrays, subsequence

[prompt for isValidSubsequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm8hV.png)

```py
def isValidSubsequence(array, sequence):
    index = -1
    # issue is with initialising the index variable 
    if len(sequence)<=len(array):
        for i in range(len(sequence)):
        # i refers to the i in the sequence 
            if sequence[i] in array:
                # causing a problem for repetitions such as array = [1,1,1,1,1] and subsequence = [1,1,1]
                # array.index(sequence[i]) would call the first 1 instead of the second 1 
                if array.index(sequence[i]) > index:
                    index = array.index(sequence[i])
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False 
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

How to solve this repeating 1s issue using my code?

Comment: Can you provide sample values for `array` and `sequence`, as well as the expected output for `isValidSubsequence(array, sequence)`?

Comment: is this hiring challenge problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason `array.index(sequence[i])` calls the first 1 is because sequence[i] is 1 in your case, and that is the same as if you called `array.index(1)`. The index function searches your array for 1 and as soon as it finds it, it returns its index, so it always finds the first 1 first and then stops looking and returns its index.

Try something like this, this should work:

```
def isValidSubsequence(array, sequence):
lastIndex = -1
if not len(array) >= len(sequence):
    return False

for i in range(len(sequence)):
    containsInt = False
    for j in range(lastIndex + 1, len(array)):
        if array[j] == sequence[i]:
            containsInt = True
            lastIndex = j
            break
    if not containsInt:
        return False
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using **list**s, not arrays. [list.index(x[, start[, end]])](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#index) can take positionals from where to where search - you *could* rewrite your algo to remember the last found position for each value and look for new values from that position.

**BUT:** this is irrelevant, you only need to concern yourself with how many of each element are in `original` and `sequence` and if one has at most equal of them...

---

The correct way to solve this ist to count the occurences of elements in the `original`, subtract the amount of occurences in the `sequence`` and evaluate your numbers:

If `sequence` is empty, contains elements not in `original` or contains more elements then inside `original` it can not be a subsequence:

```
from collections import Counter

def isValidSubsequence(array, sequence):
    # check empty sequence
    if not sequence:
        return False

    original = Counter(array)

    # check any in seq that is not in original
    if any(i not in original for i in sequence):
        return False

    # remove number of occurences in sequence from originals
    original.subtract(sequence)

    # check if too many of them in sequence
    if any(v < 0 for v in original.values()):
        return False

    return True
```

Testcode:

```
source = [1,2,3,4]
test_cases = [[1], [2,4], [1,2,4] ]
neg_test_case = [[2,5], [9], []]

for tc in test_cases:
    print(isValidSubsequence(source,tc), "should be True")

for ntc in neg_test_case:
    print(isValidSubsequence(source,ntc), "should be False")
```

Output:

```
True should be True  
True should be True  
True should be True  
False should be False
False should be False
False should be False
```

---

If you are not allowed to import, count yourself (expand this yourself):

```
# not efficient
counted = {d:original.count(d) for d in frozenset(original)}

# remove numbers
for d in sequence:
    counted.setdefault(d,0)
    counted[d] -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be another way to answer the question.

```
def isValidSubsequence(array,sequence):

    if len(array) >= len(sequence):

        iter_sequence = iter(sequence)
        last = next(iter_sequence)
        total = 0

        for i in array:
            if i + total == last:
                total += i
                try:
                    last += next(iter_sequence)
                except StopIteration:
                    return True
                    break

        return False
```